# Adding additional boards in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

In my team the list of boards, e.g. this page https://dev.azure.com/myorg/MentalHealth/_boards/directory, only contains one board, called 'MentalHealth Team boards' (N.B. I don't understand why that name is plural):

[image: ADO team boards directory screenshot]

Other teams I work with have multiple boards listed. How do I add additional team boards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't understand why that name is plural

It's plural because you can have multiple boards here. For example, you can have boards for `Epics` and `Issues`:

[image]

> Other teams I work with have multiple boards listed. How do I add additional team boards?

The `All teams boards` lists all boards of all teams, according to then img you provided, there is only one team `MentalHealth Team` in this project.

You can check `Project Settings` - `Teams` see if there is only one team in it.

In addition, you can see there are three team boards in my Boards since there are three teams in this project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to project setting -> project configuration -> areas and then add boards under existing boards by clicking on new child.
Hope this helps.